# How do I add an entity model to a .Net Core ClassLibrary using Entity Framework Core in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a .NET Core 3.1 class library.

I've added the following NuGet packages to it:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0"
```

I would like to run DataScaffold in VS 2019's Package Manager Console to create the entity model code to an existing database inside this .NET Core class library.

The prescribed steps I've read work fine when doing this with either an app or a service.

How do I do this for a class library?

There doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this through VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of  DataScaffold I higly recomment you to install "EF Core Power Tools" for VS 2019. Use reverse engineering option of this tools to create the entity model code-first from  an existing database.